# Switching to PDF Containing Window - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to verify whether a new windows is opened while clicking on 'Generate PDF' hyperlink. I don't need to validate the PDF contents, just looking to ensure that a new window is opened while clicking the test link.

I have already tried with window handles code below, but it didn't work...!!!

```
String strCurrWind = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String strTempWind:driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(strTempWind);
        }

        String strPDFUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(strCurrWind);
```

Please help me with some suggestions.... Thanks!

Comment: is the expected result to open a new tab with the PDF in all major browsers? what if you get the download pdf dialog: Save/Open?

Comment: No, the expected result is to open PDF containing page in a new window - not in tab. There won't be any download dialog with save/open...

Answer (score 0):

So if you only need to check that a new window is open:

```
int oldWindowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
driver.findElement(<By locator for hyperlink here>).click();
int newWindowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
Assert.assertEquals(1, newWindowCount - oldWindowCount);
```

Assuming you have no more than two windows open, if you want to switch between your current window and the new one:

```
String oldWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(<By locator for hyperlink here>).click();
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(oldWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope.. I don't find any difference... even I tried similar approach... **driver.getWindowHandles()** is not retrieving multiple windows count, even after clicking the test link. I also had a check on frames and switched to default content before using **getWindowHandles()**, still no luck.....!!!

Comment: Is it a timing issue? Have you debugged this and seen the second window open?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Generate PDF Link, there are two ways it can happen,

1. new browser window opens up
2. new OS based (desktop based) window opens up.

if it is a browser based window, you should be able to debug with timers or getWindowHandles

if it is a desktop based window, use ROBOT framework

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/quickstart/quickstart.html

or AutoIT is good alternative

[AUTO IT reference to handle windows pop up](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM89yVrPzNAhWJMo8KHROTDRoQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.softwaretestinghelp.com%2Fautoit-tutorial-to-download-write-autoit-script%2F&usg=AFQjCNHLEIBOsbmMbr4j8MGW0A9_6JMemA&sig2=0NjQuH1yjUHnitSW9J4U4w)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
String currentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); //gives the handles of all opened windows
for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {
    if (!windowHandle.contains(currentWindowHandle)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle); //Switching to the new tab

        driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle); //Returning to the previous page
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).